# How to debug against a same loop that generates different outputs?

Tags: loops, debugging, assembly, breakpoints

I'm learning debugging. For this purpose I'm using x64dbg. So I understood how to place breakpoints (according to strings) and how to "block" the execution of the program near the assembly code that interests me.

Unfortunately I came across some strange cases.

In some cases the "flow" is not linear. The flow "follows" a sort of loop. With each passage of this loop "something new" is written. For example. Let's say that the software has to write HELLO. At the first turn just an H appears, at the second turn just a HE, etc etc...  and I can see this in the comments column of x64dbg.

The stranger thing is that if the program has to write PIZZA, the program crosses the **SAME** loop that  previously wrote hello HELLO... but this time P appears first, then PI, then PIZZ etc etc… and I can see this in the comments column of x64dbg.

In other words, any operation I perform in the software the **SAME** piece of code is always executed, this code is executed hundreds of times (in loop) and each step contributes to a little piece of the final result (which changes).

How is it possible ? What should I do ?

Comment: That's the way it works. Otherwise, there would be distinct code for every possible value; what's that number when considering strings? If something is executed hundreds of times in a loop and you don't need/want to see it at that level of detail, go up a level and debug from there.

Comment: You've explained what you're seeing, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NateEldredge I want to be able to by-pass an instruction. In a "linear program" it's simple, just change the JUMP IF before the instruction I want to skip. But in a program that works in this way there no a JUMP linked to a single instruction.

Comment: You might be looking for conditional breakpoints; you could condition the breakpoint on some parameter value.

Comment: *How is it possible* - Clearly the block of code has inputs: registers and/or memory contents.  So it's like a step in a state machine, not like `char foo(void)`.  For example, think about how you'd write a loop that right shifts a register by 8 and stores the low byte every iteration.  Or shifts by 4 and converts the low 4-bit integer to an ASCII hex digit.

Comment: @PeterCordes As the loop progresses many "sensitive strings" appear next to the values of the EAX, EBX, ECX registers. In addition, these "sensitive strings" appear EVERYWHERE as comment lines next to the assembly code. And every step of the loop changes everything, the same piece of assembly does different things.
So far I have been successful in debugging simply by looking for a "sensitive string" in the assembly code and finding the "sensitive instruction" just above in the code (for example a TEST followed by conditional JUMP).
What should be done with a program that works like this?

Comment: Actually reverse-engineer it  / understand what it does, if necessary.  Same way you'd read uncommented source code with meaningless variable names in other languages.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok. Let's say that I understand which control I want to "skip". How do I patch it ? Because only at one time (when i breakpoint it) that piece of assembly code does that. At the next iteration forcing the same jump could blow up useful pieces of program.

Comment: That's not in general possible.  For example, the same function can be called from different places, and you might only want to change the behaviour for one caller.  You can have similar problems with a loop and only wanting to special-case one iteration.  In theory you could make the program jump to an alternate larger version of the loop that does what you want, but just NOPing instructions in the original loop can't always work.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes. From the "main level" I have several CALLS to the same address. Each of these calls is preceded by the same instructions but the values of the variables in these instructions (add word, lea, push, mov) change. Entering each of these CALLs a loop starts which writes different things with each passage.

Comment: That all sounds totally normal.  Sounds like you might want to divert that whole function to some new code you add which either jumps back to the original or runs your new modified loop.